# Google Display of top black bar

Tags: google-account

I've attached two images. I really like the first one but now I'm in a different area and it's appearing as in the second image. I've tried very hard to get back the original black bar but no success!!(Note the difference in both of images concerning the top black bar, like the font in the first case is not **bold** like the second one and the positioning of details on the right hand side).

My Question is how do I get back to the 1st display again. All the Google pages are now displayed according to the 2nd image.

**First image:**
[image]

**Second Image:**
[image]

Comment: Yes. I want to make the display of Google pages as in the 1st image. But now, every Google page(gmail, google drive etc.) open according to the 2nd image's display.

Comment: Unless you work for Google, this doesn't sound like a programming question.

Comment: @Juhana: Agree, but I didn't know where else to post this question.

Comment: You should post this question at [http://http://productforums.google.com/forum/](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!overview)

Comment: Are you developing a greasemonkey script or something like that?